# Use ToolbarFlags in PCFs to determine buttons visibility instead of availability

Tags: guidewire

I have a usecase in which I have a ListView with checkboxes and a screen referencing that ListView and containing 4 CheckedValuesToolbarButtons that need to perform an action on all the selected rows. This action could be different depending on some information in the checked rows (i.e.: the entity represented in the ListView). EntityA is the one displayed in the ListView and has PropertyA, which if it evaluates to true, the button should perform Action1 and if it's false Action2. This is easy to achieve, but customer wants the label of the buttons to change dynamically to indicate if the action to be performed is Action1 or Action2.

I didn't manage to implement this and my next idea was to duplicate the buttons and use ToolbarFlags to expose the value of PropertyA from the ListView to the buttons.
With this I could achieve what I needed, but the issue is the flag property in CheckedValuesToolbarButton determines whether the button is available, and I need it to determine the visibility of the button. I cannot use the value of the flag outside the `flags` property, so I cannot create a condition for the `visible` property based on the flags. So now I see 8 buttons every time, some of them greyed out based on the selected checkboxes.
Is there any other way to achieve this? An alternative would be to hide the button every time it is not available (or when its opposite button is available), but I'm not sure this is possible either. I think for this I would need some kind of reflection mechanism and reference the button by their ID. If anyone could guide me with this it would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Honestly this sounds to me to be a good candidate to go back to the business and say "maybe there is a better way to do this" because this requirement seems overly complicated and unintuitive to a user. From a user experience standpoint you usually want a button to perform the same action on all checked values in an LV. What data is displayed in the LV? What is the property that is being evaluated? What are the 2 different actions that are being performed based on the value of said property? A little more detail of the business use case would help me give a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I cannot talk about the specific details but a similar example would be a search page for Contacts in which you want to manage 4 specific roles for those contacts. We would have 4 buttons, one for each role, and after obtaining a list of contacts in the search you click the checkbox in some of them and if all of them already have Role X, in the button for that role the label should be "Remove Role X" and if at least one of them doesn't have the role the label should simply be "Role X"

Comment: There would also be a validation in case you select contacts with and without the role, the button would notify the user and do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you should go back to the business with a better suggestion of how to solve their use case.
2. The reason that the available property works is because it can respond to a user selecting checkboxes in the LV without posting back to the server (the greying out of the buttons based on the checkboxes selected in the LV is a client-side behavior). The visible property is evaluated on the server-side and requires a full post back to the server to redraw the UI. It would be inadvisable to implement a post back to the server every time a user selected/deselected a checkbox in an LV. Therefore, instead of trying to implement this requirement as is, I would suggest experimenting with a different (hopefully simpler and more intuitive) solution to the use case.

Comment: Thank you very much for the technical explanation and the suggestion to review the requirements with business. It really seems like the best approach for this situation.

Comment: You are welcome Enrique. Good luck!